# Know the result of 'insertIgnore' with Jetbrains Exposed

Tags: mysql, kotlin-exposed

I'm using Jetbrains Exposed to interact with my MySQL 5.7 database.
The problem I have is with `insertIgnore`.

As I see it, there is no way of knowing the result of the statement. MySQL itself will return either 1 if a row was inserted, or 0 if it was ignored because of an error (in my case, duplicate key error).
But I can't see any way to see that from the result of the insert.

My code is basically just:

```
transaction(database) {
  MyTable.insertIgnore {
    it[uniqueColumn] = "foo"
  }
}
```

Executed twice where `uniqueColumn` is unique. There is no difference in the results, although the first time is successful and the second time isn't.

It seems like an easy thing to have the resulted rows of that statement be represented somewhere, but I couldn't find anything myself or when googling.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I solved it using IntIdTable instead of Table
And insertIgnoreAndGetId instead of insertIgnore

Maybe it will help anyone

Comment: Note that the returned Id is always the one of the entity you are trying to save, not of the entity that is in the table in case of a duplicate.